# Loop in python Generator

Tags: python, generator

I was trying python's generators (together with from) but endup with infinite loop. My python version is python3. why did I stuck into infinite loop?

Below is my code:

```
def fib2():
    a,b = 0,1
    while True:    
        yield a
        a,b = b , a+b


def FibNumber(num):
    fi2= fib2()
    for i in range(num):
        yield from fi2


if (__name__ == "__main__"):
 
    fin = FibNumber(10)
    for i in fin:
        print (i)
```

Answer (score 2):

`fin` is indeed an infinite generator. `FiBNumber` doesn't do what you intended; for each value of `i`, it tries to yield *everything* from `fi2`. A more correct definition would be

```
def FibNumber(num):
    fi2 = fib2()
    for i in range(num):
        yield next(fi2)
```

However, you are really just reimplementing `itertools.islice`:

```
from itertools import islice


for i in islice(fib2(), 10):
    print(i)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have one more doubt is that when I ran this same code on pdb debugger then I noticed it was iterating over i in FibNumber method and printing Fibonacci numbers one after another. So you mean when I generated fi2 then python3 produced as much as possible big iterable and returned the iterator?

Answer (score 2):

This is due to fact that you used `yield from` with infinite generator. [PEP 380](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380/) says that:

```
yield from <expr>
```

*where `<expr>` is an expression evaluating to an iterable, from which an iterator is extracted. The iterator is run to **exhaustion**, during which time it yields and receives values directly to or from the caller of the generator containing the yield from expression (the "delegating generator").*

(bold by me)

Comment: Add a working example for the answer to be complete

Answer (score 0):

You can use the __next__() in the second iterator.

```
def FibNumber(num):
    fi2= fib2()
    for i in range(num):
        yield fi2.__next__()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `FibNumber(num)` with the following:

```
def FibNumber(num):
    fi2= fib2()
    yield from (next(fi2) for i in range(num))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to force a break in your for loop.

```
def fib2():
a,b = 0,1
while True:    
    yield a
    a,b = b , a+b

def FibNumber(num):
    fi2= fib2()
    a = 0
    for i in fi2:
       a += 1
       if a > num:
          break
       yield i

if (__name__ == "__main__"):

    fin = FibNumber(10)
    for i in fin:
        print (i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the next value of your fib2 generator for every sequence of loops.

```
def fib2(n):
    a,b = 0,1
    i = 0
    while i <=n:    
        yield a
        a,b = b , a+b


def FibNumber(num):
    fi2= fib2()
    for i in range(num):
        yield next(fi2)


if (__name__ == "__main__"):
 
    fin = FibNumber(10)
    for i in fin:
        print (i)
```